# Вложенный цикл for

Tags: java

Всем привет. Есть задача
Считать слово с клавиатуры и из символов вывести строки. Например: масло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю как сделать второй цикл для повтора букв.
Объясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом примере мы используем второй цикл, чтобы повторить символ `n-ое` кол-во раз.

```
String word = "масло";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

А в этом примере мы используем метод `repeat()`, который сам за себя говорит, что он делает. Но, так как, `charAt()` возвращает тип `char`, а метод `repeat()` работает только с `String`, нам нужно `char` привести в тип `String` (например с помощью `String.valueOf()`)

```
String word = "масло";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(word.charAt(i)).repeat(i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как вывести символы именно елочкой?

Comment: Елочка неправильное название) Хотел бы вывести с каждой новой строки по количеству знаков ( сначал м, с новой строки аа, с новой ссс, с новой лллл, и ооооо

Comment: Обновите вопрос (добавьте) и покажите пример, а то что-то не совсем улавливаю.

Comment: В описание вопроса добавил картинку

Comment: Так оно так и выведет))